# ¿Cómo saber cuantas veces se repite la A en una cadena?

Tags: python, lista, url, string, porcentaje

El URL manda directamente a un archivo de secuencia de ADN y lo que quiero sacar es el porcentaje de Adenina (A) que hay en ella. Pero cuando agrego la variable que la va a contar y la imprimo, me arroja 0. Y le agrego un contador para ver si está funcionando y ese sí funciona.

```
import urllib.request

x=urllib.request.urlopen('http://vis.usal.es/rodrigo/documentos/bioinfo/avanzada/genomas/Vibrio_cholerae.txt')
y=x.read()
z=len(y)
a=0
cont=0
for i in y:
    cont = cont + 1
    if i=="A":
        a=a+1

p=a*100/z


print(a)
print(cont)
```

Entonces quería saber ¿por qué ocurre esto? o si debo meter el URL en una lista.

Answer (score 1):

La función `x.read()` retorna un bytearray, no un string por eso la comparación que haces es incorrecta. Lo que se debe hacer es convertir el bytearray a string usando decode(), luego eliminar caracteres como `'\n'` y k usando strip(). Para hacer el conteo podemos usar el método `count()`:

```
import urllib.request

x = urllib.request.urlopen('http://vis.usal.es/rodrigo/documentos/bioinfo/avanzada/genomas/Vibrio_cholerae.txt')
y = x.read().decode().strip()
numero_de_A = y.count('A')
total_de_letras = len(y)
porcentaje_de_A = numero_de_A*100.0/total_de_letras
print(porcentaje_de_A)
```

Salida:

```
26.523076923076925
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

el problema es que al darle `read()` te retorna es un `bytearray` puedes usar el metodo `str()` o `__str__()` para hacer la conversion a string:
**Ejemplo:**

```
import urllib.request
# hacemos la solicitud a la url y la leeemos y pasamos a string
x= urllib.request.urlopen('http://vis.usal.es/rodrigo/documentos/bioinfo/avanzada/genomas/Vibrio_cholerae.txt').read().__str__()
#  contamos las letras A con el metodo str.count().
y = x.count("A")
# eliminamos los saltos de linea del string y contamos la longitud del string
z = len(x.strip())
# realizamos el calculo
p=y*100/z
# convertimos a string e imprimimos
print(str(p))
```